# Adding a constructor to a template type in typescript

Tags: typescript, class-validator

Code:

```
import { Expose, Type } from "class-transformer";
import { IsDefined, ValidateNested } from "class-validator";
interface A{
    ...
}

class B{
    ...
}
class Document<T extends A> {
    @IsDefined()
    @ValidateNested()
    @Type(()=>B)
    @Expose()
    b: B;

    @IsDefined()
    @ValidateNested()
    @Type(()=>T) //Compile error: 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
    @Expose()
    a: T;
    
    constructor(b: B, a: T){
        this.b = b;
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

1. This gives an error('T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.) in the line with @Type(()=>T). The problem seems to be that T is only a type and does not have a constructor. So, how do I add a constructor to the template in the definition so that it compiles?
2. Can I get rid of the constructor for Document without causing an error? (since I am going to use 'plainToClass' from 'class-transformer' to create the object)

Comment: `T` is a type. You're trying to use it as a value and that is not possible. Given that all types are fully erased, and by implication there is only one class that exists at run time, not one for each generic instantiation, what you're trying to do does not make sense. Note the term is generic not template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create the object you should use the constructor. There is no other way

Class **B** has own constructor even if it is not defined directly. The interface **T** is just a signature in Typescript. You can create two different classes who **implements** the same interface **T**.

You should pass the constructor to your *Document* class somehow. I see 2 ways

## Use factory

```
const documentFactory = <T>(getT: () => T) => {
    class Document<T> {
        @Type(getT)
        @Expose()
        a: T;
    }
    return Document;
}
```

## Inject constructor function with private property

There is anther, probably more elegant way in [example](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/blob/master/sample/sample4-generics/SuperCollection.ts) from library repo

As you see the **@Type()** decorator get callback with one parameter of **TypeHelpOptions** type. It has the undocumented property **newObject** who referring to class instance. So you can pass **T** constructor as parameter of **Document** constructor and use it in **@Type()** callback

Comment: In the example to inject constructor function with private property, the `options` variable can be null. So, this gives an error. This is undocumented, so what is the correct way to handle it? And is the `newObject` guaranteed to have the correct object type? I am getting my data from network, so I want the validation to work correctly to avoid security holes in my application.

Comment: I can not help much there..  The example is placed in library repo. In the library there is no place where options parameter is not passed to typeFunction. You can check it [https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/search?q=typeFunction]. But there is no guaranty that  it will never happen with next lib updates  :-D. Probably you should look for other library, if it possible